# Avoid stretching photos

Tags: php, css, image, resize, stretch

How can I avoid the stretching of my photos? PHP selects 2 photos at random from a folder and displays them using `echo`. But right now, all photos in portrait, are stretched.

```
<?php if(!empty($images)) {
    $rand_key = array_rand($images, 1);
    $src = $images[$rand_key];
    echo "<img class=\"flickrphoto\" src='".$src."' align='absmiddle'>";

    unset($images[$rand_key]);
    $rand_key = array_rand($images, 1);
    $src = $images[$rand_key];
    echo "<img class=\"flickrphoto\" src='".$src."' align='absmiddle'>";
} else {
    echo 'Error';
} ?>
```

And the CSS:

```
.flickrphoto {
    max-width: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

** EDIT **
Current code:

```
   // protrait calculations;
    $size = getimagesize($images_folder_path);
    if($size[0] < $size[1]) {
        $orientation = 'portrait';
    } else {
        $orientation = 'landscape';
    }
```

Comment: Stretched how? I don't see anything that would stretch an image beyond its natural width and/or height here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd just check if the orientation is protrait or not and add a css class;

```
<?php if(!empty($images)) {
$rand_key = array_rand($images, 1);
$src = $images[$rand_key];

// protrait calculations;
$fullpath = // statement to fetch the path on the server
$size = getimagesize($fullpath);
if($size[0] < $size[1]) {
   $orientation = 'portrait';
} else {
   $orientation = 'landscape';
}

echo "<img class=\"flickrphoto ". $orientation ."\" src='".$src."' align='absmiddle'>";

unset($images[$rand_key]);
$rand_key = array_rand($images, 1);
$src = $images[$rand_key];
echo "<img class=\"flickrphoto\" src='".$src."' align='absmiddle'>";
} else {
    echo 'Error';
} ?>
```

and in your css somthing like this:

```
img.flickrphoto {
    max-width: 100px;
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
img.flickrphoto.portrait {
    max-width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: This seems like a good solution, except the portrait calculation is always giving the `landscape` property... Any idea how?

Comment: have you printed out the $size[0] (which should be the width) and the $size[1] (height) vars? maybe there's something wrong with that. Or could it be that you images aren't "really" portrait and landscape but just differ in aspect ratio? In that case you should do something like this: $ratio = $size[0]/$size[1]; $orientation=($ratio > 1.2)?'landscape':'portrait'; (where you should find out what the 1.2 bit should be)

Comment: The code I adjusted right now is stated in my original post. Maybe I did something wrong? The `$images_folder_path` is my path to the folder (`images/photos/`)

Comment: @Michiel Instead of `$images_folder_path` when you check for the orientation, you will need something like `$images_folder_path . $src` to get the complete path to the image you just randomly selected.

Comment: but is it the full server path? (which is something different then the 'web' path, eg; full server path /images/photos/ isn't the same folder as http://example.com/images/photos/), -- edit: and check @Michiel 's comment!

Comment: so I should be using `mysite.com/images/photos` in stead of `images/photos`?

Comment: no you should use the internal path to the folder. ask your webhost what the path to the document root is (folder where your index.php is stored), or just run the following: <?php echo $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']; ?> This would output the full path to the script running this code, which should give you enough info to construct the full path to the folder where your images are stored

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good article on how to maintain aspect ratio with CSS and HTML:

http://haslayout.net/css-tuts/CSS-Proportional-Image-Scale

Also, there is a SO question that gives a couple ideas on how to do this as well:

[HTML - display an image as large as possible while preserving aspect ratio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160666/html-display-an-image-as-large-as-possible-while-preserving-aspect-ratio)

Basically, you need to scale either height or width but not both.

Answer (score 0):

display them as background of a `<div>` instead of `<img>`

like this:

```
echo "<div class=\"flickrphoto\" style='background: url(".$src.");'></div>";
```

Comment: That's not a good suggestion, since then they won't scale down if they need to.

Answer (score 0):

use php functions imagesx and imagesy, and emit the return values as the width and height attributes of the image tag.

Comment: No need for that, this should be solvable using CSS.

Comment: @horatio When you don't even understand why the CSS is not working, you should not be so eager to jump to a solution that eats resources on the server.

Comment: I understand that it is not working because he is specifying a (max-)height and a (max-)width without regard to the aspect ratio of the picture, it is imperative that he determines whether the picture is "portrait" or "landscape" aspect ratio. This can be done ont he server or the client. I find it touching that you care about the function call time and resources, but the answer is not wrong.

Comment: That would be great to include in your answer, then, and I certainly wouldn't downvote a full answer illustrating the source of the problem.

Comment: giorgio has already worked that out, albeit with `getimagesize` rather than `imagesx` and `imagesy`