# Image object in HtmlTemplate

Tags: google-apps-script

A rather simple question but does anyone know why I can call a Image object in an HtmlService template? Like this:

```
<script>
var myImage = new Image();
</script>
```

I get the following error:

```
Image is not defined.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oranje

Google Apps Script uses [Caja](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/) to filter unsafe javascript from user's code. You may try [Caja Playground](http://caja.appspot.com/) to check what happens with your code. If you get the same error there, then the culprit is Caja, not Google Apps Script

Comment: I guess the culprit must be caja then as the error does also appear in the playground. Thanks I hadn't thought of that. I guess I'll either file a bug there and try to find another way of resizing image the image source like this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160666/html-display-an-image-as-large-as-possible-while-preserving-aspect-ratio

Comment: AS per the caja guys: "We'll look into adding this to Caja, but for now, you can replace new Image() with document.createElement("img") which is supported."